# php sending parameters through a link from page1 and firing up javascript on page 2

Tags: php, javascript

on page 1, I try to pass some parameters through a url to page2.
I want to fire up page2 and select the options as if i selected them on page2.

How can I pass #divOptionToTake, #divSelectChannel_btnSubmit, #selected_channel_new, #selChannels, #frmSelectChannel from page 1 and get it executed? Thanks.

**Page1**

...../page2.php?selected_channel=facebook&option_to_take

**Page 2**

```
<html>

  <script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function() {

        <?php if($option_to_take == ""){ ?>
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#divOptionToTake'), css: { width: '420px' } }); 
        <?php } ?>

        // SELECT CHANNEL
        $('#divSelectChannel_btnSubmit').click(function() {                
            $.unblockUI();
            $('#selected_channel_new').val($('#selChannels').val())
            $('#frmSelectChannel').submit();
            //return true;               
        });            

    });  
  </script>

</html>
```

**The code of the form is here.**

```
<form name="frmSelectChannel" id="frmSelectChannel" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="select_channel" />
<input type="hidden" name="option_to_take" value="new campaign" />
<input type="hidden" name="selected_channel" id="selected_channel_new" value="facebook" />
<div id='divSelectChannel'>
        <select id='selChannels' class='span3'>
                        <option value="facebook" <?php echo (($selected_channel == "facebook") ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>facebook</option>
                        <option value="twitter" <?php echo (($selected_channel == "twitter") ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>twitter</option>                                                         
        </select>
            <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' id='divSelectChannel_btnSubmit' value='Submit' />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input class='btn' type='button' id='divSelectChannel_btnBack' value='Back' />
        </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: So.. you want to manipulate page 2 with selections from page 1?

Comment: yeah. also want to get how to pass the parameter from page 1. and fire up page 2

Comment: I was referring to the form of page1; I apologize for not specifying.

Comment: dnt have it actually. but its just a normal form with GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the values of your url using the `$_GET` global variable; an example of how to do this:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['option_to_take']) {
    $option_to_take = $_GET['option_to_take'];
}
else {
    $option_to_take = '';
}
?>
```

If I misunderstood what you want, please let me know so I can modify this answer.